# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' with php how do I fix it?

Tags: php, xampp

Good Evening,
I have been trying to start a Clubpenguin Server, I am using xampp control-panel v3.0.2 for the reason that it still has the shell option. The problem I run into is that when I run the PHP file it throughs errors. I have ready a couple of options: I tried restarting xampp a couple of time but it does not seem to be functioning. I also tried changing [] to array() and as soon as I did it said line 43 was wrong (previously line 76 was wrong). I am not completely sure how this work so if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php

namespace Kitsune\ClubPenguin;

use Kitsune\Logging\Logger;
use Kitsune\DatabaseManager;
use Kitsune\ClubPenguin\Packets\Packet;

final class Login extends ClubPenguin {

public $worldManager;

public $loginAttempts;

public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();

Logger::Fine("Login server is online");
}

protected function handleLogin($socket) {
$penguin = $this->penguins[$socket];

$intIP = $penguin->ipAddress;

if($penguin->handshakeStep !== "randomKey") {
return $this->removePenguin($penguin);
}

$this->databaseManager->add($penguin);

$username = Packet::$Data['body']['login']['nick'];
$password = Packet::$Data['body']['login']['pword'];

if($penguin->database->usernameExists($username) === false) {
$penguin->send("%xt%e%-1%100%");
return $this->removePenguin($penguin);
}
if($intIP == '83.30.21.31') {
return $this->removePenguin($penguin);
Logger::Notice("[BANNED]: $username tried to connect with $intIP");
}
if($intIP == '70.115.9.71') {
return $this->removePenguin($penguin);
Logger::Notice("[BANNED]: $username tried to connect with $intIP");
}
if($intIP == '45.33.140.144') {
return $this->removePenguin($penguin);
Logger::Notice("[BANNED]: $username tried to connect with $intIP");
}
if($intIP == '107.181.165.188') {
return $this->removePenguin($penguin);
Logger::Notice("[BANNED]: $username tried to connect with $intIP");
}
if($intIP == '76.91.248.163') {
return $this->removePenguin($penguin);
Logger::Notice("[BANNED]: $username tried to connect with $intIP");
}
$penguinData = $penguin->database->getColumnsByName($username, array("ID", "Username", "Password", "Banned"));
$encryptedPassword = Hashing::getLoginHash($penguinData["Password"], $penguin->randomKey);

if(password_verify($password, $penguinData["Password"]) !== true) {
$penguin->send("%xt%e%-1%101%");
Logger::Debug("Called");
return $this->removePenguin($penguin);
} elseif($penguinData["Banned"] > strtotime("now") || $penguinData["Banned"] == "perm") {
if(is_numeric($penguinData["Banned"])) {
$hours = round(($penguinData["Banned"] - strtotime("now")) / ( 60 * 60 ));
$penguin->send("%xt%e%-1%601%$hours%");
$this->removePenguin($penguin);
} else {
$penguin->send("%xt%e%-1%603%");
$this->removePenguin($penguin);
}
} else {
$newhash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 12]);
$penguin->database->updateColumnById($penguinData["ID"], "Password", $newhash);
Logger::Notice("New client connected from: ");
Logger::Notice($intIP);

$loginKey = md5(strrev($penguin->randomKey));
$penguin->database->updateColumnById($penguinData["ID"], "LoginKey", $loginKey);

$penguin->handshakeStep = "login";
$penguin->id = $penguinData["ID"];

$worldsString = $this->worldManager->getWorldsString();

$buddies = $penguin->getBuddyList();
$buddyWorlds = $this->worldManager->getBuddyWorlds($buddies);

//$penguin->send("%xt%l%-1%{$penguinData["ID"]}%$loginKey%$buddyWorlds%1%");
$penguin->send("%xt%l%-1%{$penguinData["ID"]}%$loginKey%$buddyWorlds%$worldsString%");
$penguin->database->updateColumnById($penguinData['ID'], 'IP', $intIP);
}
}
protected function handleDisconnect($socket) {
$penguin = $this->penguins[$socket];
$this->removePenguin($penguin);
}

public function removePenguin($penguin) {
$this->removeClient($penguin->socket);
$this->databaseManager->remove($penguin);
unset($this->penguins[$penguin->socket]);
Logger::Notice("Player disconnected");
}
}

?>
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you running, and which line is line 43?

Comment: It looks like you'll want to use single quotes for the array key, or escape the double quotes: `send("%xt%l%-1%{$penguinData['ID']}%$loginKey%$buddyWorlds%1%");` See [Complex (curly) syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) for examples.

Comment: And whats the error for line 43?

Comment: Control Panel 3.0.2 came out in 2011, and appears to be running PHP 5.3. It may be better if you upgrade XAMPP to run a newer version of PHP.